# How to setup Puppet server?

Tags: networking, puppet

I would like to setup Central Management Server (PUPPET) to manage all clients. I have read many documentations, but none of them was helpful. Can anyone explain setting up puppet server in detail?

Where we have to create the following files in server or in client?

> Now setup some resources for apache2. Create a file
>   `/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`  containing the following:
>
> ```
> package {
> 'apache2':
>     ensure => installed
> }
>
> service {
> 'apache2':
>     ensure => true,
>     enable => true,
>     require => Package['apache2']
> }
> ```

Comment: Do you want this from installing to a working prototype? It might be better to ask for specific problems ;) From what I can tell they call the server `Puppetmaster` and `/etc/puppet/` seems to point to a client.

Comment: This page seems to be thourough and explains things rather nicely: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki

Comment: The files in `/etc/puppet/manifests` are only used at the server.

Comment: On the client, can you run `puppetd --test --debug` and post the contents?

Comment: You ask several different questions and the way your question is formulated at the moment is confusing in that it's unclear what you need help with and what you've solved. This site works best if you ask one at question a time and if you clearly describe your situation and what guide you use.

Comment: Yeah fine that would be better. I will ask it as a seperate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the existing docs didn't help you it's quite unlikely that just writing a new one will work better for you.

Instead please follow the explanation given in the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/puppet.html) and tell us what doesn't work for you and what additional questions you have.