# Centralized managment of some computers

Tags: updates, system

We have three computers with Ubuntu connected to a LAN network. Each computer has the software each user installs, and updates are done when the users want to update. These computers share among them a hard disk of several TB.

We would like our computers to have the same software, and to be updated all at the same time. Moreover, we would like each user to know the available resources that there are in each computer. This way they might launch a process in a computer or in another depending on the available resources.

Do you know a way to do it? What do you recommend?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "We would like our computers to have the same software"... your suggestion does not answer this issue.

Comment: Also [How to setup Puppet server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59097/how-to-setup-central-management-server)